# Changing Input Source on my TV with Google Home

Tags: smart-home, google-home, google-assistant, chromecast

I'm using my big monitor in 2 modes
1) to work (Macbook connected via USB-C)
2) to chill (Chromecast connected via HDMI)

There are problems with automatically switch the input source. When my Macbook is connected via USB-C and I ask my smart speaker to play something on my TV, I need to manually choose the HDMI as an input source.
When HDMI is chosen and I connect my Macbook, I also need to manually choose USB-C. Is there a way to automate it? Or at least switch it through voice command?

Answer (score 1):

This will entirely depend on your monitor.

If it supports HDMI [CEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumer_Electronics_Control) then the Chromecast will be able to change the input source to the HDMI when it starts to play something, but you won't be able to switch back to the Mac input via Google Assistant.

CEC is not normally available on monitors, it is normally reserved for TVs that have multiple devices as inputs e.g. set top boxes, DVD/Blueray players, Games console.

Comment: My monitor is Philips 436M6VBPAB and it has HDMI-CEC. I can turn on and off the monitor via Chromecast.

Answer (score 0):

Google support answered that they are not supporting changing input sources currently, but they created a task for that after the request, so fingers crossed, it will be working in the future.